# Unexpected errors while experimenting with dl4j-examples in IntelliJ

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, dl4j

I'm trying to experiment with the dl4j-examples  project and added a test "Hello World" java class to it where I copied and pasted the code

```
String filePath = new ClassPathResource("raw_sentences.txt").getFile().getAbsolutePath();
```

from class `Word2ecRawTextExample` and it gives the error `Unhandled exception: java.io.FileNotFoundException` at `.getFile()`, but it worked fine in the  `Word2ecRawTextExample` class. I tried Invalidate cache and restart but that didn't work.
The other thing is when I add any new class IntelliJ starts giving  errors even in the sample projects, when I didn't even change them at all. In this case

```
Error:(22, 8) java: class Word2ecRawTextExample is public, should be declared in a file named Word2ecRawTextExample.java
```

at the line

```
private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Word2VecRawTextExample.class);
```

Is there any way to download the maven dependencies in a new project without using the dl4j example projects, I tried looking up about but couldn't find anything useful.

Comment: why do you think these errors are unexpected?

Comment: @Stultuske because if a package/lib is imported in one class and its methods are working fine there, then if I import the same package in a new class and call the same method it should work fine there also.

Comment: at the very least, this one "Error:(22, 8) java: class Word2ecRawTextExample is public, should be declared in a file named Word2ecRawTextExample.java" should be clear

Comment: @Stultuske Yes it does, but it occurs when I didn't change any original code! This is just one error I got this time, in my previous attempt I created a new module and then IntelliJ couldn't read any maven dependencies.

Comment: it isn't complaining about the  code, but about the name of the file the code is in.

Comment: Yes sorry, that second error was a typo mistake, the class was "Word2VecRawTextExample". But now it says "java: package org.deeplearning4j.rl4j.space does not exist" and the previous error on .getfFile() is still there.

Comment: Hi, this should just be a 1 click import if you are following our getting started. After that, each pom in the examples project is for different use cases like spark, the ui etc. Rather than asking on stack overflow about this, why not engage with us directly? We provide multiple ways to contact us. That would be a better dialog. We encourage the examples because usually people want to worry about dependencies "once" and then they can get to work.

Comment: so, you copied that line, but you didn't copy the code that handles the Exception.